# php and R integration

Tags: php, r

I have php call an R script. When I call R from my php script to do some simple calculations like t-test I get a solution back. However when I call an R script that takes around 30 secs to execute and print the output I don't get anything. I know that the R script works fine as I've tested it. Is it possible that php is timing out or what could be the reason I get output for simple r scripts but when I try to call an R script that takes some time to finish running I don't get anything?

Comment: How is this question different from the one you asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023660/run-r-in-php-under-ubuntu

Comment: would you be so kind to put a reproducible example? are you using RApache or smth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [PHP Time Limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

call `set_time_limit(0);` at the start of your PHP script.